# Fastest way to sum the elements of a matrix

Tags: matlab, sum, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient, space-efficiency

I have some problems with the efficiency of my code. Basically my code works like this:

```
a = zeros(1,50000);
for n = 1:50000
    a(n) = 10.*n - 5;
end
sum(a);
```

What is the fastest way to solve the sum of all the elements of this matrix?

Comment: What is the performance issue in this small piece of code? There is no faster way than `sum` **to calculate the sum** as far as I know. However, you can generate the `a`-matrix easier like this: `n = 1:50000; a = 10*n - 5;`

Comment: (1) oops. my bad. just edited the post. (2) i was just wondering if there was a faster way to do the sum. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you want to remove your for loop by making it a vector multiplication:

```
tic
a = zeros(1,50000);
b = [1:50000];
   a = 10.*b-5;
result = sum(a);
toc
Elapsed time is 0.008504 seconds.
```

An alternative way is to simplify your operation, you are multiplying 1 to 50000 by 10 and subtracting 5 then taking the sum (which is a single number), which is equivalent to:

```
tic
result = sum(1:50000)*10 - 5*50000;
toc
Elapsed time is 0.003851 seconds.
```

or if you are really into Math (this is a pure mathematical expression approach) :

```
tic
result = (1+50000)*(50000/2)*10 - 5*50000;
toc
Elapsed time is 0.003702 seconds.
```

and as you can see, a little math can do greater good than pure efficient programming, and actually, loop is not always slow, in your case, the loop is actually faster than the vectorized method:

```
tic
a = zeros(1,50000);
  for n = 1:50000
     a(n)=10.*n-5;
  end
sum(a);
toc
Elapsed time is 0.006431 seconds.
```

---

### Timing

Let's do some timing and see the results. The function to run it yourself is provided at the bottom. The approximate execution time `execTime` is in seconds and the percentage of improvement `impPercentage` in %.

#### Results

- R2016a on OSX 10.11.4

  ```
                 execTime     impPercentage
                __________    _____________
  loop          0.00059336         0       
  vectorized    0.00014494    75.574       
  adiel         0.00010468    82.359       
  math          9.3659e-08    99.984
  ```

#### Code

The following function can be used to generate the output. Note that it requires minimum *R2013b* to be able to use the built-in `timeit`-function and `table`.

```
function timings
%feature('accel','on')      %// commented out because it's undocumented
cycleCount = 100;
execTime = zeros(4,cycleCount);
names = {'loop';'vectorized';'adiel';'math'};
w = warning;
warning('off','MATLAB:timeit:HighOverhead');
for k = 1:cycleCount
    execTime(1,k) = timeit(@()loop,1);
    execTime(2,k) = timeit(@()vectorized,1);
    execTime(3,k) = timeit(@()adiel,1);
    execTime(4,k) = timeit(@()math,1);
end
warning(w);
execTime = min(execTime,[],2);
impPercentage = (1 - execTime/max(execTime)) * 100;
table(execTime,impPercentage,'RowNames',names)


function result = loop
a = zeros(1,50000);
for n = 1:50000
    a(n) = 10.*n - 5;
end
result = sum(a);

function result = vectorized
b = 1:50000;
a = 10.*b - 5;
result = sum(a);

function result = adiel
result = sum(1:50000)*10 - 5*50000;

function result = math
result = (1+50000)*(50000/2)*10 - 5*50000;
```

Comment: These timings are not representative since you only executed it once. Do it 10'000 or more times to see that the vectorized solution is more than 3 times faster.

Comment: Why all this...? Simply `a=10*(1:50000)-5` is much faster than any of those options.

Comment: @Matt nope, I am getting similar performance results, do you want to share your code/answer so I can try to recreate it?

Comment: @Adiel nope again, you are missing the sum of the matrix part, and how can this method be faster than my second and third method?

Comment: @Adiel in fact my third solution is over 50 times faster than your solution. Please share your code/timer result to compare.

Comment: Ok, checked again. Your second option is almost the same as mine. But still, the first and the third are completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Adiel The first one is a standard vectorized version to look just like the OP's code, the third is actually much faster than your code as it involves 2 additions and 4 multiplications.

Comment: So... very interesting. I ran your codes as you wrote it, in three lines: `tic`, `result...`, `toc`. But, if I run it in the same one line (as I run mine), it suddenly becomes hundreds of time faster... This worth a separate question... Indeed, your third is the faster.

Comment: @Adiel the third one uses only pure math expressions, I do not think any method can be faster than this; I iterated 10000 times just to show how much faster the third method really is.

Comment: Simplest solution: `result = 12500000000;` ;)

Comment: @GameOfThrows I get 1.757s and 6.628s with your 10'000-times script. Something seems strange here, but I can't see what it is. Check [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EYjSr.png).

Comment: @Matt this question has been edited to a community wiki, maybe someone else could explain/edit the different results we are getting.

Comment: @Matt I haven't seen anyone mention versions yet. There has been a huge overhaul of the MATLAB execution engine recently, and basic computations like these might have drastically different relative performance. That, and `tic/toc` is not a precise way to measure performance. All code should be put in full named functions to let the JIT compiler do its job, `tic/toc` needs to be warmed up (but using `timeit` is even better where available), and results should not be compared between major MATLAB versions.

Comment: @AndrasDeak This is a really good point to consider... `timeit` seems like handy way to measure the execution time of a function since it runs it multiple times internally and therefore provides a more accurate result. [Here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html) are some more tips if you didn't know this page of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for adding the timing performance @Matt, I had the version 2010b when I was testing this.